# Chainlink: How to get the jobspec for a specific feed?

Tags: chainlink

I am trying to determine the off-chain source of price data for a feed. From reading the docs, this is declared in the job spec.

So, given a specific price feed, https://market.link/feeds/9765bb8d-2b71-4c75-9ede-57972addc5ee for example, how do I find the jobspec and/or determine the off-chain ground truth of the feeds?

Comment: Node operators are the ones running the job specs, at the moment, you'd have to ask the individual operators, or do some analytics to compare their results to off-chain resources.

Answer (score 0):

The link you shared is for the feed itself. On the "jobs" tab, you should be able to search for the equivalent pair and the click on the "job spec" tab. That should take you here https://market.link/jobs/e829bec3-7017-47a8-bb25-0ba1da763067/spec. Good luck.

Comment: This works for this specific feed, but for other feeds, https://market.link/feeds/000f3807-e5c4-4922-92aa-c81b2e5dba19, for example, there is no matching job that can be found.